# Wordpress need to add parent Category (custom taxonomy) to items

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, parent

I am working on a Wordpress website using a custom post type and custom taxonomy(tour-category).

I am making changes to the search filters the below bit of code pulls in the taxonomies(tour-category) and displays them so you can filter them on and off to update the search.

I have managed to add the category slug to the div class but really I need them to display the **parent** taxonomy(tour-category). on the div class for each of the filter items.

So I can target any taxonomy(tour-category) under a specific parent using CSS as I want to be able to hide none relevant ones, without having to hide them one by one I will just target all that are under a parent.

Hope someone can help :-)

Thanks
Lee

```
<?php if(is_array($tour_types) && count($tour_types) && $show_tour_types) : ?>
   <?php foreach($tour_types as $type) : ?>
        <?php
        $checked = in_array($type->slug, $checked_types);
        $checked_attr = $checked ? 'checked' : '';
        ?>

    <div class="mkdf-tours-type-filter-item <?php echo esc_attr($type->slug); ?>">
        <input <?php echo esc_attr($checked_attr); ?> type="checkbox" id="mkdf-tour-type-filter-<?php echo esc_attr($type->slug); ?>" name="type[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($type->slug); ?>">
        <label for="mkdf-tour-type-filter-<?php echo esc_attr($type->slug); ?>">
            <span>
                <?php echo esc_html($type->name); ?>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: here is a guide with *hierarchical* taxonomy: https://wpmayor.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-wordpress-taxonomies/